# javafx User interface not updating?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, properties

I'm new to JavaFX.
I'm building a GUI for a project of mine, and I have a problem with it -
it seems that once I show my UI it stops updating.
In my case, it supposed to update a fill colour for a circle but it does not.

I tried to move the line:
someCircleId.setFill(color));
to be above the line:
Main.stage.show();
in the initialize function in my code and it did change the color of
the certain circle.

```
public class UIController implements Initializable {
            public UIController() {
                fillMap();
            }
    @Override
            public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
                Main.stage.show();
            }

            @FXML
            public void pressExitButton() {
                Main.dropDBSchema();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        public void changeCircleColor(String circleKey, Color color) {
            Platform.runLater(
                    () -> {
                        Circle circle = this.circles.get(circleKey);
                        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(10));
                        delay.setOnFinished(event ->  circle.setFill(color));
                        delay.play();
                    }
            );
        }

                }
```

And this is the class that uses these functions:

```
public class MonitoringLogicImpl implements MonitoringLogic {

    public void updateUI(UUID flowUUID, String sender, String receiver, DATA_STATUS status){
        String key = flowUUID.toString()+"_"+sender+"_"+receiver;
        Color color = this.uiController.getColorAccordingToStatus(status);
        this.uiController.changeCircleColor(key, color);
    }
   }
```

This is the FXML initialization :

```
public void start(Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface.fxml"));
            this.root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stage.setTitle("Troubleshooting project");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 700));
        stage.show();
    }
```

I created my UI using Scene-Builder tool.

Comment: where are you calling `changeCircleColor` ? this too `getColorAccordingToStatus` ?

Comment: Post a [mcve]. One circle should be enough to demonstrate the issue; check if FXML initialization is really needed; we don't need the circles map or the `DATA_STATUS` either...

Comment: There is no FXML initialization in this class. It happens only one time in the main class

Comment: The code you presented isn't enough to figure out the problem check @user1803551's comment

Comment: I changed my question. Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Read the link I posted and follow the instructions there. We need to be able to copy-paste the code into our IDE, launch it, and see the problem. Create a new project and follow those steps.

Comment: You refuse to read the link. Your question has 3 out of 5 close votes due to lack of a [mcve].

Comment: I read the link and changed my question according to it; Some want more code and others less code; Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Copy-pasting this code into my IDE produces many compilation errors. Create a new project and copy-paste this code into the new project. Fix the compilation errors and make sure that when it is ran the problem manifests. Remove all unnecessary code.